# Scheduling a phone call

Tags: time

I'm arranging an international phone call with somebody I speak to for the first time, after exchanging short business emails.

Here are the options I can think of

> Thanks. I'll be available anytime after 6 pm BST as long as ...

> 1. you (can?) fix the schedule

> 2. you fix the time

> 3. you pick the schedule

> 4. you decide what time

> 5. you tell me what time

What I want to say is I can make time for a call anytime after 6 pm but I will not be able to pick up a call if I'm bathing my 3yo, for example, so I need the other guy to tell me what time we will have a call beforehand. (I don't know much about his availability, by the way.)

Maybe native speakers use a totally different structure of sentence?

Actually, first of all, is "time" or "schedule" correct word for this kind of "6 pm or 7 pm" thing?

I wasn't taught this kind of, what I might call "secretarial" English at school so it took 20 min just to *ask* this question...

Comment: I don't think you *can* explain to a new business contact about family matters, or make the conditions too detailed. Give them a simple date or range of dates, and a time window of 1 or 2 hours that you think will work in both time zones, and make yourself available. Take the trouble to put it in *their* local time, not make them work out whether BST (daylight saving time) is in force. So: "I will be available to receive your phone call from Monday to Friday [specify the date range] between 7pm and 9pm (your time). Please let me know if others times are more convenient."

Comment: "I will be available for the phone call anytime after 6 pm British Summer Time" is enough. And as Weather Vane said, take the trouble to put it in their local time is a common courtesy